# Passing data from one page to another using StateProvider in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a ListPage.html which has a table with two columns. The first columns has the Id and next column has the name.

```
                                   <table class="table">

                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Name</th>>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="" ui-sref="app.details" style="text-decoration: underline">1</a></td>
                                            <td>First Value</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="" ui-sref="app.details" style="text-decoration: underline">2</a></td>
                                            <td>Second Value</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

When I click on the link I want the value to be passed to the next page. Like, when I click on the first row I want value 1 to be passed to the next page. The values loaded in the table are dynamic and would be coming from a web service.I have a router.js which is now taking it to a different page when the user clicks on the link.

Router.js

```
    export default ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
  $stateProvider


    .state('app.details', {
      url: '/details',
      template: require('./details/index.html')
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}];
```

Could you let me know how I could pass the data from the ListPage.html to this page using the state provider.I want to show the ID in the url and display it in the details page.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your value with your ui-sref tag as an argument:
ui-sref="app.details({test: '1'})"

Add it to your url in .state():
url: '/details/:test'

Catch it in your other controller with $stateParams library:
$stateParams.test